# ATOM does not show updates in folder/files nor GIT repo updates

Tags: git, atom-editor

I have some problems with ATOM lacking of reload/refresh for adding/updating folders/files.

Environment: OS: Ubuntu 18.04 ATOM: 1.52.0

**Problem area:**

1. Deleting/Changing folders and files does not automatically reflect, without having to double-click on a parent folder.
2. When checking out a branch ATOM does not show the checkout branch, unless you double-click on a parent folder.

To clarify, the changes are such are there, but one have to double-click each time, to see the change. This makes it very difficult to work effectively especially to introduce GIT branch handling.

I do recall that the reload did work previously.

**What works**

Updates in ATOM are visible when adding a folder/file.

Comment: Give up atom, there are bugs!

Comment: @Spikie. I am totally fine with ATOM, if above can be solved.

Comment: During my using of atom, there are always problems related to git, which is my nightmare.

Comment: @Pikie. I get your point. So what do you suggest in terms of IDE setup for system dev? I actually am considering using VIM as a base and enhance it with needed parts, such as "tree view", "emmet", "language color", etc.

Comment: After I gave up atom, I have been using IntelliJ IDEA and vscode. Currently,, these two IDEs have basically no problems, and they are more powerful.

Comment: All IDEs are basically code editor + button to run shell command lol. why would I download 10 gb only to add one button? Also most of them are not made on electron or other web technologies so it's a lot harder to customize them and develop plugins. And finally, the worst is that they are expensive and there are no torrents for macos, and all free IDEs such as vscode has the same functionality. This is why I use Atom for years and don't switch to different software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be solved by increasing the handles of file watcher. Problem occures because the workspace is large and contains many files. Add or update below line in following file: /etc/sysctl.conf.

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```